# When a new db is imported in a Laravel project it can't run new migrations properly

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I recently imported new db to my local server and now when I created a new table and tried to migrate, it shows

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'migrations.PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (2022_10_17_071124_create_team_histories_table, 11))

So, basically the system has started **inserting the migration table id(pk) from 1** but right now my **migration table has 39 rows**(1-39 filled up). As a result when I run `php artisan migrate` **it migrates** the table but **doesn't add** the table **record** in the **migrations table**, thus any further migrations will fail with a error saying "the last_table_name already exists"

Now one way to solve this problem is to migrate the table then drop it and keep doing it until the system tries to insert 40 as the id of migration table.

So, I have have to migrate and drop my table 39 times to get there. This trick may work for very small db, but when it gets larger it's not really a solution rather it's another problem :v.

Any efficient solution will be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: Well, by importing into the database, you've also imported the migrations table and messed up the migrations. Only update the database using migrations in the future. If you want to import data only, exclude the migrations table.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind from the next time. However, are you sure that this will solve the issue? @GertB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is not very clear.

### Manage application base data

If your application need seeders for some table (ie populating a table that contains basic data), make seeders part of the migrations.

### Data Import from another application

If you need to do a complete data import from another application, then do a complete database dump including migration table.

```
mysqldump --opt
```

With this option, [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) will include in your dump also the table creation and drop table statement

Then after data import, run migrations.

Migrations will run only if the codebase you are using has more recent migrations than the application from where you have dumped data

### None of the above is an option

If this is not an option, maybe you can't do a dump again, you can try to fix the counter column by running

```
alter table migration AUTO_INCREMENT=39;
```

Of course adjust the 39 to your need